# Angular factory not being instantiated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I have angular 1.4 app. Im using require.js. An included script have this:

```
define(['firstFactory', 'secondFactory'],
function(firstFactory, secondFactory){
    var app = angular.module('services', []);
    app.factory('firstFactory', firstFactory);
    app.factory('secondFactory', secondFactory);
});
```

Inside require.config (in main.js) I have path to both the factories:

```
"firstFactory" : "factory/firstFactory",
"secondFactory" : "factory/secondFactory"
```

Finally in my main controller I have this:

```
function myCtrl(firstFactory, secondFactory) {
```

Thing is that in firstFactory.js I have this code:

```
define([], function () {
    console.log('inside define firstFactory');
    var firstFactory = function () {
        console.log('inside function firstFactory');
    };
    return firstFactory;
});
```

While in the secondFactory.js I have this:

```
define([], function () {
    console.log('inside define secondFactory');
    var secondFactory = function () {
        console.log('inside function secondFactory');
    };
    return firstFactory;
});
```

In the console I see:

```
inside define firstFactory    
inside function firstFactory
inside define secondFactory
```

So I dont see

```
inside function secondFactory
```

Why? To me the symptom is that angular is not instantiating the second factory. I cannot understand that for the first one it is being instantiated but not for the second, as Im doing the same thing with both. Any clue?

Comment: Could you create a fiddle or plnkr?

Answer (score 0):

In the secondFactory.js you are returning firstFactory, may be this is the reason.